# MySQL REGEXP not producing expected results (not multi byte safe?). Is there a work around?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to identify first name fields that actually contain initials. The problem is that the query is picking up records that should not match.

I have tested against the POSIX ERE regex implementation in RegEx Buddy to confirm my regex string is correct, but when running in a MySQL query, the results differ.

For example, the query should identify strings such as:

'A.J.D' or 'A J D'.

But it is also matching strings like 'Ralph' or 'Terrance'.

The query:

```
SELECT *, firstname REGEXP '^[a-zA-z]{1}(([[:space:]]|\.)+[a-zA-z]{1})+([[:space:]]|\.)?$' FROM test_table
```

The 'firstname' field here is VARCHAR 255 if that's relevant.

I get the same result when running with a string literal rather than table data:

```
SELECT 'Ralph' REGEXP '^[a-zA-z]{1}(([[:space:]]|\.)+[a-zA-z]{1})+([[:space:]]|\.)?$'
```

The MySQL documentation warns about potential issues with REGEXP, I'm unsure if this is related to the problem I'm seeing:

> Warning The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so
>   they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with
>   multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare
>   characters by their byte values and accented characters may not
>   compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `... WHERE firstname REGEXP ...`?

Comment: This is just an example query that shows the result against the row in this case.

Comment: A clarification. The documentation warning applies to characters that require more than one byte to be stored. This requires that you use a multi-byte encoding (e.g., `latin1` is unaffected) and you have multi-byte characters (e.g., regular English letters on UTF-8 are unaffected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing this in the mysql client, you need to escape the backslashes. Each occurence of `\.` must turn into `\\.` This is necessary because your input is first processed by the mysql client, which turns `\.` into `.`. So you need to make it keep the backslashes by escaping them.